# Run react-native run-ios and react-native start in one command?

Tags: ios, react-native

I just upgraded from RN 59 to RN 60.2 and `react-native run-ios` used to both start the Metro Bundler and then also open the simulator and run the app, no longer does. They now need to be separate commands.

I'm not sure how to run both `react-native start` and `react-native run-ios` as one command because `start` does not terminate itself so there's nothing telling run-ios to run.

Here's what I currently have for scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone 11\"",
    "rename": "node ./bin/rename.js",
    "start": "react-native start",
}
```

And my idea would be something like:

```
react-native start && react-native run-ios
```

The best alternative so far has been to run them backwards and have it build the app then start the Metro Bundler:

```
react-native run-ios && react-native start
```

This causes the simulator to first launch to an error message of the bundler not being online, and then runs the server, which then lets me reload the simulator. This is less than ideal.

Are there alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0):

okay so try this way

```
"custom":"react-native run-android && react-native start"
```

and then you are directed to run 'npm run custom' in you terminal once you get in the root of project where package.json is located.

Comment: That doesn't work per the reasons in the question. When you do it like that it first launches to an error screen since the bundler isn't up yet.

Comment: I am using rn 0.60.x in this release this line is working fine, as rn does not suppose to open the app automatically in this release. so if you are facing hurdles you can modify the code.